# Parsing json using deserialize in abap btp environment

Tags: json, eclipse, parsing, abap, json-deserialization

I fetched the data from a URL and data is stored in a variable in json format.now i need to parse this json format but i am unable to parse the data.
below is the code

```
CLASS zcode_82 DEFINITION

  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_oo_adt_classrun .
    DATA:lv_response TYPE string,
         lv_body type string,
         lv_path type string,
           lv_json     TYPE /ui2/cl_json=>json,
         r_json type string.

types: begin of ty_data,
       field type string,
       id type string,
       customer type string,
       customer_id type string,
       address type string,
       date_Created type string,
       time_created type string,
       END OF TY_DATA.



data: lv_data type STANDARD TABLE OF ty_data with DEFAULT KEY,
       lr_data    TYPE REF TO data,
      ls_data type ty_data.

  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.


CLASS zcode_82 IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
    DATA: lv_body_1 TYPE string,
          ls_value type RANGE OF ty_data.
    TRY.
        "create http destination by url; API endpoint for API sandbox
        DATA(lo_http_destination) =
             cl_http_destination_provider=>create_by_url( 'enter the url ' ).



        "create HTTP client by destination
        DATA(lo_web_http_client) = cl_web_http_client_manager=>create_by_http_destination( lo_http_destination ) .
        "adding headers with API Key for API Sandbox
        DATA(lo_web_http_request) = lo_web_http_client->get_http_request( ).
        lo_web_http_request->set_header_fields( VALUE #(
        (  name = 'Authorization' value = 'Bearer key' )
        (  name = 'Content-Type' value = 'application/json' )
        ) ).
        "set request method and execute request
        DATA(lo_web_http_response) = lo_web_http_client->execute( if_web_http_client=>get ).
        lv_response = lo_web_http_response->get_text( ).
      CATCH cx_http_dest_provider_error cx_web_http_client_error cx_web_message_error.
        "error handling
    ENDTRY.

*  out->write( |response:  { lv_response }| ).
*
CLEAR lv_data[].

/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize(
  EXPORTING
    json             = lv_Response
*    jsonx            =
    pretty_name      = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-user
*    assoc_arrays     =
*    assoc_arrays_opt =
*    name_mappings    =
*    conversion_exits =
*    hex_as_base64    =
  CHANGING
    data             = lv_data
).
out->write(
  EXPORTING
    data   = lv_data
*    name   =
*  RECEIVING
*    output =
).
endmethod.
endclass.
```

Here the downloaded data from url is the input and the input is

```
response:  {"records":[{"id":"rec5Qk24OQpKDyykq","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010001","address":"Chennai","created_time":"06:00:14","customer":"IDADMIN","date_created":"16.04.2004"}},{"id":"rec7bSe8Zb18z6b5a","createdTime":"2022-08-08T13:07:16.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010007","address":"Kakinada","created_time":"04:01:18","customer":"Ramya","date_created":"15.04.2000"}},{"id":"recD9Hh4YLgNXOhUE","createdTime":"2022-08-08T11:48:06.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010002","address":"Bangalore","created_time":"04:03:35","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"20.04.2004"}},{"id":"recK7Tfw4PFAedDiB","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010005","address":"Chennai","created_time":"06:00:49","customer":"IDADMIN","date_created":"21.04.2004"}},{"id":"recKOq0DhEtAma7BV","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010006","address":"Hyderabad","created_time":"18:42:28","customer":"GLAESS","date_created":"21.04.2004"}},{"id":"recS8pg10dFBGj8o7","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010003","address":"Gurugram","created_time":"04:10:02","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"20.04.2004"}},{"id":"recf4QbOmKMrBeLQZ","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010004","address":"Bangalore","created_time":"06:00:12","customer":"IDADMIN","date_created":"21.04.2004"}},{"id":"recs7oHEqfkN87`enter code here`tWm","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010000","address":"Hyderabad","created_time":"04:01:18","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"15.04.2004"}}]}
```

The output of the code is

```
Table  
FIELD  ID  CUSTOMER  CUSTOMER_ID  ADDRESS  DATE_CREATED  TIME_CREATED
```

Comment: `but i am unable to parse the data` what exactly goes wrong? give actual result vs expected

Comment: actaul result is field
excepted results is
fields
customer customer_id     address
Ramya     0000010007     kakinada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure type simply does not match the JSON structure. You can't simply skip the outer `records` array and expect the deserializer to know you want to deserialize what is within it. Same with the `fields` object to string, it's an object/structure, not a string.

The JSON <> ABAP type would look like this

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "id":"rec5Qk24OQpKDyykq",
         "createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z",
         "fields":{
            "customer_id":"0000010001",
            "address":"Chennai",
            "created_time":"06:00:14",
            "customer":"IDADMIN",
            "date_created":"16.04.2004"
         }
      },
      ...
```

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_field,
         customer_id TYPE string,
         address TYPE string,
         created_time TYPE string,
         customer TYPE string,
         date_created TYPE string,
       END OF ty_field.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_record,
         id TYPE string,
         createdtime TYPE string,
         fields TYPE ty_field,
       END OF ty_record.
TYPES tt_record TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_record WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_response,
         records TYPE tt_record,
       END OF ty_response.
```

Then you can use a variable like `DATA ls_response TYPE ty_response` as your `data` parameter.

Side note: If you can, consider using [Simple Transformations with JSON data](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenabap_st_json_table_abexa.htm). There you can fine-tune namings (mix snake_case and camelCase), which fields to serialize, deserialze, require/optional, and it's magnitudes faster (especially with larger json files).

Comment: the link which you pasted in the comment is useful but i am trying this code in eclipse sap btp environment and it shows error as transformations are not permitted. is there any other code as to consider as reference.
I tried using split and deserialize the splited data but only data before fields is fetched.

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS You can use the code you are using with the type definition I provided. You might also check the ABAP XCO library for JSON support

Comment: the output  shows  as that the data type is not supported

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS Where? Works perfectly fine for me: https://pastebin.com/DxKiL9AN

Comment: I saw that code  in the link which you pasted and when i try that in eclipse it show error in this last line
out->write( ls_response->records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id ).
here it says that "LS_RESPONSE IS NOT A REFERENCE VARIABLE".

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS `ls_response` is not a reference, so you must use `-` instead of `->`, so `out->write( ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id )`

Comment: out->write( ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id  ).
now its shows error as  that ls_response-records is not an internal table

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS can you share your code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/H4CKm7x6

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS `records TYPE ty_record,` is wrong, must be `records TYPE tt_record,` as in my answer ;)

Comment: hey it worked 
now i want 2 more fields in it  like customer but it is not accepting like this
out->write( ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id fields-customer
how to get 2 fields in a single line

Comment: Check [this](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenstring_templates_expressions.htm) and [this](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenstring_templates.htm) and [this](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenstring_operators.htm)

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS `out->write( |{ ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id } { ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer }| )` would be one option. Or `DATA(ls_first_entry) = ls_response-records[ 1 ]. out->write( ls_first_entry-fields-customer_id && \` \` && ls_first_entry-fields-customer ).`

Comment: thanks for the code and one more query how to display the data with headings like
customer id    customer
000000100     Ram
is this option is avaialble?
like the data is displayed under the headings
like cl_demo_display in sap gui
here in eclipse this function is not available

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS I'd open a new question for that so people with more experience can comment on that. And please provide the environment and abao language version you are working with in there

Comment: I am working on Sap btp environment in eclipse
Can you please provide that you raised question link
I think it's above 7.4 version

Comment: can we convert the out->write( |{ ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer_id } { ls_response-records[ 1 ]-fields-customer }| )  this output into json again 
when i did the serliaize  it gave me the output " { } " like this.